# rendering twitter standard search api

Tags: php, twitter

how do i render twitter standard search api

reference:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

my code

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array('oauth_access_token' => "XXX",'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXX",'consumer_key' => "XXX",'consumer_secret' => "XXX");

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = "?q=#XXX from:XXX";

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}

var_dump($string);
```

it giving me response similar to the reference above

my problem is how to render it? I can't find any documentation/example about this?

like embedded time line and oEmbedAPI

reference:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/guides/oembed-api

Comment: ruling out obvious answers: you're replacing all `xxx`'s with actual variables. I've also notices that you have a space in your `$getfield` this wil not work. Parse your entire built string through `http_encode()` so spaces would be rendered as `%20` for example.

Comment: regardless if I change the space to %20 it's still work BTW thanks for the tip appreciated

Comment: I did get my function wrong, so for clarity you should be using `urlencode()` so it would look like this `$encoded = urlencode($getfield);` and then you parse `$encoded` like so `setGetfield($encoded)`. This is also just a general tip if you're taking random crap from an uncontrolled front-end